# Installing Apyori package in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Question: How to install apyori algorithm in Python using Jupyter Notebook.

Code:
`! pip install apyori`

Error:
[image: AttributeError]

Solution:
what can be the solution to it?

Comment: Although there's a different problem in your case, you should be aware that it is best to no longer use an exclamation point with `pip install` . A special magic command that makes sure the installation happens in the environment backing the notebook kernel was added. Use `%pip install <package_name>`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about the modern magic install commands for use inside Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

This is on the first github page I've found.

```
Install with pip pip install apyori.
Put apyori.py into your project.
Run python setup.py install.
```

from apyori import apriori

Comment: I'd argue that last suggestion of the three [listed there](https://github.com/ymoch/apyori#installation) is vague and/or incomplete. You'd need to clone the repo before running that command, right? The second one pointed out by tudorifim, would be the easiest. You can just download the script and place it in your current working directory.